# How to add Oracle ODBC 64 bit to 32bit Oracle client

Tags: excel, oracle11g, odbc, ms-office

Having a question on Oracle. Computer has Oracle 11.2 32bit Client installed(win is 64bit) However, downloaded Office x64 and want to connect to OracleDB. 
 I have tried to download from Oracle page Oracle Instant Client Basic, inserted into it x64 ODBC Instant Client, made a path in environments to it and launched CMD installation, and got message that it was successfully installed. However, when i launch ODBC Administrator, and try to add System DSN of OraClient , i do not see possible options for 64bit ODBC connection.
[image]
Where can be the problem? Oracle client is installed in C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1 and x64 ODBC connection with Instant Client i have put  in C:\oracle\instantclient_11_2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows has two versions of odbcad32.exe:

- The 32-bit version of the odbcad32.exe is located in the %systemdrive%\Windows\SysWoW64.
- The 64-bit version of the odbcad32.exe is located in the %systemdrive%\Windows\System32.

To add a 64-bit DSN, you need to start odbcad32.exe from %systemdrive%\Windows\System32.

Comment: Thank you looks like i can reach connections from here